# How to add a external data src to my service worker generation in gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, workbox

followed the install instructions from workbox gulp example here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/get-started/gulp

```
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', () => {
        return workbox.generateSW({
            globDirectory: buildDir,
            globPatterns: ['**\/*.{html,png,css,js,ico,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,jpg,json}'
            // swSrc: 'sw.js', isn't working in generator
            swDest: buildDir+`/sw.js`,
            clientsClaim: true,
            skipWaiting: true
        }).then(() => {
            console.info('Service worker generation completed.');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.warn('Service worker generation failed: ' + error);
        });
    });
```

and all is running very fine.

BUT now I want to add an external source to my SW generation.

It's written here how to add e.g. external google font source to a service-worker script: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/next/

I'm not sure how to add that to my generator in gulp.

I thought it could work like that option:

```
globPatterns: ['**\/*.{html,png,css,js,ico,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,jpg,json}','^https://fonts.(?:googleapis|gstatic).com/(.*)'],
```

I also tried to include a custom script with that option. but it's not possible with the generator. said an error.

```
swSrc: 'sw.js',
```

Would I need a second custom service worker for external sources outside of my gulp script?

**edit**

maybe i will find an answer in here: [Workbox build with grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990281/workbox-build-with-grunt)

Answer (score 0):

sorry to answer your own question.

YES you can add, by changing your gulp script like so:

```
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', () => {
    return workbox.generateSW({
        globDirectory: buildDir,
        globPatterns: ['**\/*.{html,png,css,js,ico,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,jpg,json}'],
        runtimeCaching: [
            {
                urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://fonts.(?:googleapis|gstatic).com/(.*)'),
                handler: 'cacheFirst',
                options: {
                    cacheName: 'font-cache',
                    cacheExpiration: {
                        maxEntries: 10,
                    },
                },
            }
        ],
        swDest: buildDir+`/sw.js`,
        clientsClaim: true,
        skipWaiting: true
    }).then(() => {
        console.info('Service worker generation completed.');
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn('Service worker generation failed: ' + error);
    });
});
```

this will add used external google fonts to cache.